# Access to DOM methods in angular app

Tags: angular, svg

I am using SVG in the angular 5 app and I have hard dependency on accessing DOM level methods such as:

createSVGPoint();

this is how embedded SVG looks like:

```html
<svg id="mainSVG" no-padding
    viewBox="0 0 480 480"
    preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet"
    width="100%"
    height="100%"
    itemtype="background"
    shape-rendering="auto"
    color-rendering="optimizeSpeed"
    image-rendering="optimizeSpeed"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
    ><svg:g id="svgCanvas" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 0 0)" class="contained" svgcanvas [canvasItemsDataObject]="canvasItemsDataObject" [canvasBackgroundDataObject]="canvasBackgroundDataObject"></svg:g>
</svg>
```

So the way i do it now is pretty bad I guess:

In ngAfterViewInit() i call: this.mainSVG = document.getElementById("mainSVG");
then I can sort of access methods directly by using: this.mainSVG.createSVGPoint(); etc

I know I am not supposed to access DOM directly using this method, but I am confused as to what is the proper path?

What I tried and could not achieve:

1. use ViewChild: 
   added #mainSVG to the html template and did @ViewChild('mainSVG') mainSVG2: ElementRef; and I can't use this,mainSVG2.createSVGPoint().
2. in the init function do something like:
   this.mainSVG = this.renderer.selectRootElement('#mainSVG');

Still doesn't work for me;/

**What is the proper way to gain access to DOM level methods of SVG elements?**

Comment: could you share your angular code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using your approach #1, you should be able to call the dom method that way

```
@ViewChild('mainSVG') mainSVG2: ElementRef
//...
mainSVG2.nativeElement.createSVGPoint()
```

Comment: Hey yo, testing this now!

Comment: genious! let x = this.mainSVGViewChild.nativeElement.createSVGPoint();
    console.log(x) worked! so is this a safer method to access DOM?

Comment: OK I just moved every DOM access pattern that I had over to this approach. Went pretty smooth. Only had one complication with regards to items that are modules. But this was resolve thanks to the other thread here (had to add explicitly to read those ViewChilds as ElementRef). Thanks  ALOT!